# MS Access - FIlter subform based off listbx

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to filter a subform based off a value selected in a listbox.
My list box is called cboCurrentListName and this is populated using a select query

The subform is called Form_subform_ListContents

For the change event for the list box I have the following code, however no filters are applied when its executed.

```
Me.Form_subform_ListContents.Form.Filter = "[ListName]=" & Me.cboCurrentListName.Value
Me.Form_subform_ListContents.Form.Filter = True
```

I have also tried using Master/Child links to execute this using the following steps, but this caused an input box to pop up when the fom loaded:

- first I set the 'link child fields' option in the properties of the subform to 'ListName' (this is the field name that populates the list box and is present in the subform
- then I set the 'link master fields' option in the properties of the subform to 'cboCurrentListName' (the listbox name)
- then in the listbox properties I set the control source to 'cboCurrentListName'

The above steps cased an input box to pop up on opening the form (the value typed in here does filter the subform). However I don't want an input box in order to do this, I want to use the listbox.

I have googled this and fried different methods but have had no luck. I am pretty new to access and of the control source sections aren't a strong point of mine, which is why I tried to use the VBA on the event change instead

Any help would be appricaited, I tried a few things and had no luck.

EDIT: When trying the master/hild option I also get an error 'Can'y build a link between unbound forms' if I click the 3 dots in the poperties. SO for the above steps I had to manually type in the otpions.

Comment: That should read `.FilterOn = True`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it and it now applies a filter however in order for the filter to be applied an input box pops up where I have to specify what I have clicked. It also only works one time, so if I change the selected option a second time the filter does not change. Would you know why this is happening?

Comment: I presume the *ListName* is text and the *ListBox* has a single column. If that's the case, then you need to wrap the value in `'` quotes: `.Filter = "[ListName]='" & Me.cboCurrentListName.Value & "'"`.